using commas after the "replace" word not working
My autocorrect in Word has recently stopped me from being able to use commas after the replace word to get the with word followed by a comma, although it still works with periods.  For example, I use the replace word "yh" for the with word "Your Honour"  I used to be able to type "yh," and get "Your Honour," but now when I type "yh," it doesn't give with the with word and just stays "yh,"  Yet when I type "yh." I still get "Your Honour."  This is very frustrating and I really need it to go back the way it was.  Any suggestions on how to reverse something I may have done or to fix this would be GREATLY APPRECIATED.

What build of Office/Word is installed on your computer?

Don't know, but have you tried escape character, e.g., , before comma?

It's Microsoft Word 2019, and I'm sorry I don't under the the escape character advice

If the Windows desktop application, look under File > Account for the update number. The latest in the current channel is 2408 or 2409.

That number is 2408

Taking a bit of a guess, try checking your Auto-correct options.
In MS Word, Go to File > Options > Proofing and select AutoCorrect Options.
Then in the table under 'Replace text as you type', check for an entry for 'yh,' and if it's there, select it and hit the Delete button.
MS Support link to the menu I'm talking about:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/turn-autocorrect-on-or-off-in-word-9f5a0684-05f6-4510-b419-8f0034caefe4
HTH

Thanks for the suggest, but the yh was just an example, unfortunately, I am not able to put a comma after a replace word and have it work at all anymore, is the issue

And the replace text as you type is clicked
